# (Rails) How to create both sides of a friendship from one nested form insert in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, ruby-on-rails-5, mutual-friendship

Basically I have a User model, and a Friendship join table to make the Users friends with each other.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships, class_name: 'User'
```

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
```

Simple, right? Now I have a collection check box for each user's edit page to decide who is their friend:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes( :friend_ids, @other_users, :id, :full_name) do |b| %>
  <%= b.label(class:"form-check-label") { b.check_box(class: 'form-check') + b.text } %>
<% end %>
```

When I check off John on Timmy's edit page, I would like for two join tables to be created, one linking the User (Timmy) to the Friend (John), and another linking the Friend to the User. At the moment, there is only one table being created:

```
Friendship Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO `friendships` (`user_id`, `friend_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (48, 49, '2023-09-21 14:24:36', '2023-09-21 14:24:36')
```

I tried adding a callback to the friendship model

```
  after_create do |ship|
    friend_friendship = Friendship.create(user_id: ship.friend_id, friend_id: ship.user_id)
  end
```

But obviously that failed, creating an endless loop!

How do I also create the friend-to-user join without a fuss? Thanks

Comment: The big con of modeling it this way is that you get really awkward queries since you don't know if the user is in the user_id or friend_id column. If you instead have a friendships table and a user_friendships join table then you can avoid that problem.

Comment: By awkward queries  I mean stuff like: `User.joins(:friendships).where("friendships.friend_id = :a OR friendships.user_id = :a AND friendships.friend_id = :b OR friendships.user_id = :b")` to check for a mutual friendship.

Comment: @max Okay, I'll look into it.

Answer (score -1):

[accept_nested_attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) is something that will do the trick.
You also need to create a join model too.

Lets see an example, to undersand the basic -

```
#==== 3 model associations here===
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :friends
  has_many :friendships, through: :friends
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :Friendship
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends
  has_many :users, through: :lines
end


#===== View ====== 
<%= nested_form_for @user do |f| %>
...#user attributes
<%= f.fields_for :friends do |friend| %>
<%= friend.label :name %>
<%= friend.collection_select(:friendship_id, Friendship.all, :id, :name , {include_blank: 'Select friends'} ) %>
```

**The association class Friend will join users and Friendship through the friendship_id and user_id:**

Comment: You start good with idea idea of a join table but then it all falls apart. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` isn't going to create the `Friendship` and two rows in the `friends` table that are needed. The naming is also very awkward as `user.friends` gets the join table rows belonging to that user and not the other users as you may expect.

Comment: If I had to do this on the model layer I would create a setter that takes a list of user ids and creates a friendship and the two needed join table rows.

Comment: @max - I am not here to write exact runnable code, i am here to give an idea about how it can be done, rest of the things can be taken care on exact code editors.